# Proxy creation wizard Wso2 ESB

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

Hello I would like to implement a sort of wizard for my boss to create a new proxy for the wso2 Esb.

It should not be really complicate, just matter of adding an `inSequence` and possibly a `UsernameToken` security (from the ESB built-in security scenario).

1) Is that possible? I mean it should since is matter of writing an XML, but I don't know how I can really achieve that? Do you have any suggestion?

2) If I do a java application that writes an XML in the proper folder of the ESB (I think it is "`ESB_HOME\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\proxy-services`"), will I need to restar the ESB to get the new proxy working?

Any suggestion? many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try WSO2 Developer Studio, It meant to do just that.

However if that's not what you need, you can of course write a GUI client or a Wizard, and generate the proxy template and push it to synapse-configs\default\proxy-services. If hot deployment is enabled it will be picked up immediately. else you have to restart.

I am not exactly clear about your #3 requirement. IMO, you are trying to get the URL of the proxy service. for all the services the URL has a pattern, so its basically a constant string + the proxy name that you are using.

Comment: don't worry for the 3rd requirement I have deleted it because I realized can just get the "To" parameter and combine localhost:portnumber/services/"proxy name". I don't know how can I use Developer Studio to create programmatically a new Proxy Service based on a template. I have also thought that if there is the possibility I could create a new Template and put it in the "Manage panel>Add>Proxy Service" ... but don't know where the templates are